# Automatically set drive letters after SysPrep

Tags: windows, hard-drive, sysprep

After syspreping a machine all drive letters are reassigned. How do I prevent this from happening or automatically reasign drive letters after sysprep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use diskpart for that. Create text file that contains the diskpart command and then use diskpart /s mydiskpartscript.txt

the diskpart text file would be:

```
select volume 2
assign letter=D
select volume 3
assign letter=R
exit
```

Comment: Correct, but I'm looking to automate this process.
If others interested in what Mathieu is talking about you can look at the following links for more info.
http://forums.techarena.in/server-deployment/491210.htm
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465(WS.10).aspx

I found the part I was looking for:
Basically under sysprep.ini I'll add the following command, which will reference the diskpart.exe command like you mentioned.
[GuiRunOnce]
Command0 = C:\AssignDriveLetters.cmd

Comment: sorry , i should have explained the guirunonce in sysprep too